# Find two integers such that their product is close to a given real

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, integer

I'm looking for an algorithm to find two integer values `x,y` such that their product is as close as possible to a given double `k` while their difference is low.

**Example**: The area of a rectangle is `k=21.5` and I want to find the edges length of that rectangle with the constraint that they must be integer, in this case some of the possible solutions are (excluding permutations) `(x=4,y=5)`,`(x=3,y=7)` and the stupid solution `(x=21,y=1)`

In fact for the `(3,7)` couple we have the same difference as for the `(21,1)` couple

`21.5-3*7=0.5 = 21.5-21*1`

while for the `(4,5)` couple
`21.5-4*5=1.5`

but the couple `(4,5)` is preferable because their difference is `1`, so the rectangle is "more squared".

Is there a method to extract those `x,y` values for which the difference is minimal and the difference of their product to k is also minimal?

Comment: For 33, do you want 3*11, 5*6, or 6*6?

Comment: What is more important, that the difference is small or that the product be close to the target?

Comment: How about take the square root and round it up and down?

Comment: It seems that difference from the real to the int is most important, then the difference between the numbers. For for 33 it would be 3 and 11. For 33.5 it would also be 3 and 11 because that's 8 difference compared to 2 and 17 which is 15 different. For 32.5, 4 and 8 is a better answer than 3 and 11 though.

Comment: Since `4,5` is preferable to `3,7` despite being further from 21.5, you've prioritized minimizing `|x-y|` over minimizing `|x*y - k|`. So the preferable answers are where `x == y`. Then the only question left to resolve is which square number is closest to `k`. Which as Nemo says, will be the square of either the ceiling or the floor of the square root of `k`. I suspect that in fact there's a limit to how important it is for the rectangle to be "more square" as opposed to "more accurate", but you haven't described how you want to resolve the tension between the two.

Comment: Since int * int can never be 21.5, start by rounding/truncating k to an integer, then ponder the algorithm after that. I don't see how it would be meaningful in the real world to examine what two ints that can be used to produce a particular float number.

Comment: @Lundin: He can't start be rounding or truncating k. If k is 21.5, he doesn't know in advance whether x*y = 21 or x*y = 22 will give a better solution. If he picks the wrong one, he'll get the wrong answer.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz He'll get the wrong answer no matter what he does, if he mixes int and float. Either pure int or pure float makes sense, some in-between hybrid does not.

Comment: your problem is not clearly defined. There are two factors to keep in mind when finding those 2 integers x,y whose product is closest to p: we have to consider x-y and p-x*y. Maybe you can come up with something like a formula, let's say the quality of x,y is calculated like this: f(p-x*y)+g(x-y) where f,g are two functions -> then your problem will be well defined.

Comment: I agree, probably I should weight the two conditions with some real-valued numbers. The preferable thing is the difference between the factors X and Y to be small.

Comment: @linello: Then X and Y should always be the same, since that's the smallest possible difference.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: yes but this is only possible when k is a perfect square number, like 36, 49, 64 etc...

Comment: @linello: No matter what k is, you can always make the difference between the factors X and Y zero. If the preferable thing is that the difference between the factors X and Y be small, then it should be zero.

Comment: Sounds like both requirements come directly from management. At some point you need to find a way to explain that they're mutually contradictory, and that you need new requirements which acknowledge that.

Answer (score 3):

You have to look around square root of the number in question. For 21.5 sqrt(21.5) = 4.6368 and indeed the numbers you found are just around this value.

Comment: What about 2,991? 3 x 997 is exactly 2,991 and there's no other way to get that. 3 and 997 are nowhere near the square root, which would give you 54*55 which is 2,970.

Comment: Or even try 18.888 the answer is 19*1 and your approach will never find it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz this is true, but see Steve Jessop's comment on the original question regarding the minimising of `|x-y|` in preference to minimising `|x*y - k|`. This seems to suggest that the correct answer, 3 x 997 is less desirable.

Comment: I think the question is trying to indicate that getting the product as close as possible is top priority. The most square shape is the second priority. I agree that it's unclear, but I think that's the most plausible reading.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: if it's *trying* to indicate that's the top priority, then it spectacularly fails. In the only example given (`k = 21.5`) the question specifically says that the answer `(4,5)` is preferred to `(3,7)`. But it's silent on the issue of whether `(5,5)` would be preferred even more due to being even squarer.

Comment: I thought the OP clarified it, but then he seems to have changed his mind yet again. :/

Answer (score 2):

You want to minimize

1. the difference of the factors *X* and *Y*
2. the difference of the product *X × Y* and *P*.

You have provided an example where these objectives **contradict** each other. *3 × 7* is closer to *21* than *4 × 5*, but the latter factors are more square. Thus, there cannot be any algorithm which minimizes both at the same time.

You can weight the two objectives and transform them into one, and then solve the problem via [non-linear integer programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming):

```
       min c × |X × Y - P|  +  d × |X – Y|
subject to X, Y ∈ ℤ
           X, Y ≥ 0
```

where *c, d* are non-negative numbers that define which objective you value how much.

Answer (score 1):

Take the square root, floor one integer, ceil the other.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main(){
    double real_value = 21.5;
    int sign = real_value > 0 ? 1 : -1; 
    int x = std::floor(std::sqrt(std::abs(real_value)));
    int y = std::ceil(std::sqrt(std::abs(real_value)));
    x *= sign;

    std::cout << x << "*" << y << "=" << (x*y) << " ~~ " << real_value << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this approach only gives you a good distance between `x` and `y`, for example if `real_value = 10` then `x=3` and `y=4`, but the product is `12`. If you want to achieve a better distance between the product and the real value you have to adjust the integers and increase their difference.

Comment: try your solution for 18.888. The correct output is obviously 19 * 1

Answer (score 0):

1. Let given double be K.
2. Take floor of K, let it be F.
3. Take 2 integer arrays of size F*F. Let they be Ar1, Ar2.
4. Run loop  like this

   ```
   int z = 0 ;

   for ( int i = 1 ; i <= F ; ++i )
   {
      for ( int j = 1 ; j <= F ; ++j )           
      {
          Ar1[z] = i * j ;
          Ar2[z] = i - j ; 
          ++ z ;            
      }
   }
   ```

You got the difference/product pairs for all the possible numbers now. Now assign some 'Priority value' for product being close to value K and some other to the smaller difference. Now traverse these arrays from 0 to F*F and find the pair you required by checking your condition.

For eg. Let being closer to K has priority 1 and being smaller in difference has priority .5. Consider another Array Ar3 of size F*F. Then,

```
    for ( int i = 0 ; i <= F*F ; ++i )
    {
       Ar3[i] = (Ar1[i] - K)* 1 + (Ar2[i] * .5) ; 
    }
```

Traverse Ar3 to find the greatest value, that will be the pair you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
double best = DBL_MAX;
int a, b;
for (int i = 1; i <= sqrt(k); i++)
{
    int j = round(k/i);
    double d = abs(k - i*j);
    if (d < best)
    {
        best = d;
        a = i;
        b = j;
    }
}
```

Comment: adding some explanation to accompany the code will help this answer